# Yaml regex syntax utf8 for Symfony route

Tags: php, regex, symfony, yaml

I've got a Symfony route that looks the following in xml:

```
<route id="fos_user_resetting_reset" pattern="/reset/{username}">
    <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Resetting:reset</default>
    <requirement key="_method">GET</requirement>
    <requirement key="username">%user_username%</requirement>
</route>
```

I am using here a placeholder to replace the "%user_username%" with the following parameter of a regex.yml file (to avoid duplications of regex requirements):

```
parameters:
   # user
   user_username:      "[a-zA-Z0-9s'\-@._#]+"

   #token
   general_token:      "[a-zA-Z0-9\-_=]+"
```

In general, this approach is working fine, but the posted regex above (user_username) throws an error that I can't retrace:

> Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier ']' (500 Internal Server Error)

This behaviour is weird, because all my other regex expressions within this file work, just the "user_username" one is failing.

Comment: Where's the `preg_match`? That usually means the delimiter is being used in the expression unescaped.

Comment: Try with `[a-zA-Z0-9s'\-@._\#]+` (escape `#`) commonly used as delimiter. Also your error says `Unknown modifier ']'` - that's the next to `#`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonny, working like a charm. I did not know that "#" is used as a delimiter - I am not so fit in regex expressions.

Comment: @user3746259: This is not really your fault; I’d even say this is a bug in SF2 … however, one that will most likely not be fixed.

Comment: Ok, but in general my approach of creating one regex.yml file for all url requirements, that each pattern can be reused in more url patterns is a good approach?